# setup:upgrade stuck exit at installing Data

Tags: magento2, setup-script, setup-upgrade

I have created following `Setup Script`

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $attributeCode = 'custom_attr';

        $entityType = ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE;
        $setId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityType);
        $groupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityType, $setId);

        $groupName = $eavSetup->getGroupName($entityType, $setId, $groupId, 'attribute_group_name');

        $eavSetup->addAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode, [
            'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
            'frontend_class' => 'validate-email',
            'required' => 0,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'searchable' => 1,
            'group' => $groupName,
            'sort_order' => 80,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, when I am running `setup:upgrade`, the process is getting stuck at `Installing Data`.
What is the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried any direct modifications in the database tables?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora No direct modification in the database.